# AJAX call doesn't display the data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I got this code that calls a partial view in an MVC3 application:

```
$("#TypeID").change(function ()  {

    var taskID = $('#TypeID').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/controller/_causeList',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: "Id=" + taskID,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#CauseID').html(data)

        }
    });

});
```

What I want to happen here is that when I change one drop down list, another list will be reloaded elsewhere in the form. But the reloaded drop down list is empty. Checking the script in firebug shows that the response contains the proper HTML for the selectList, it looks and works exactly as I expected it to up to that point. But I am not managing to reinsert the returned data into the page. Am I doing something obviously incorrect, I am quite new to AJAX.

Comment: try to add an error case to see if it goes in there :) check for error case ajax on google.

Comment: Sure HTML you get is **exactly** the HTML you would put inside #CauseId element?

Comment: Show the html where the element `CauseID` is defined. Is the id unique? Youy have checked, that your `success` function gets called? Show the html, that is returned in the var `data` in your callback

Comment: OK by changing the design of the partial view:  
`<select id="CauseID" name="CauseID">   
@foreach (var item in Model)
 {
 <option id="@item.TypeID">@item.Name</option>
 }
</select>`  

I removed the select tags from the partial view and put them into the parent view, so the partial view only renders the <option></option> part. Now it works.

Comment: So is there an accepted method in marking this question solved?